# How to hide one property in JSON response which is used in different apis (Public and Internal)

Tags: java, spring-boot

One POJO is used in different apis (Public and Internal), Need to hide a field in public api json response but it should be available in internal api response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson Json, you can do it using `JsonViews`

```
public class MyApiViews{
 public static class Both{}
 public static class Internal extends Both{}
public static class External extends Both{}
}
```

Now in your Pojo, use @JsonView on field level like

```
public class MyAPI{

@JsonView(MyApiViews.Both.class)
private String field1;


@JsonView(MyApiViews.Internal.class)
private String field2;

@JsonView(MyApiViews.External.class)
private String field3;

}
```

Now, if you are using Spring etc, you can use

```
@JsonView(MyApiViews.Internal.class)
@RequestMapping("/test")
```

Comment: Hi Chetan, Yes we are using spring boot. 
We have huge json payload (there are around 200 fields in JSon response) if we use @JsonView at every field level it will be more code changes. Could u suggest me minimal changes

Comment: Not sure if there are any other solutions with in built support from Spring. Creating own classes with limited fields for each use case may be too much and would require much more code than this one.